# Get 404 error updating docusign user profile via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

Here is the REST URI that I am trying to use and I am getting a 404 Not Found error.

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/318241/users/e854cadf-9f87-47d9-b9ff-c5b3da80f6f5/profile

REST Uri From API documentation:
/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/profile

Here is the JSON that I am posting:

{  "companyName" : "Company ABC",  "title" : "Project Manager" }

I have tried using authenticating with both a user that has admin rights in the account and the user that has User Id - e854cadf-9f87-47d9-b9ff-c5b3da80f6f5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me.  I just tested and was able to get it to work just fine using the same request body that you have pasted here.  Here's the full program in PHP that works for me:

```
<?php

// Input your info here:
$integratorKey = '***';
$password = '***';
$email = "***";
$name = "***";
$userId = "***";
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

//*** STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

// --- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

//*** STEP 2 - Modify User Profile

$data = array( "companyName" => "DocuSign Inc.", 
               "title" => "Technical Program Manager" );
$data_string = json_encode($data);     

$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/users/$userId/profile" );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Accept: application/json",     
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "PUT request sent, status is $status";

curl_close($curl);
```

?>

Comment: There must be a disconnect on the values that I am using for the username, password, and accountId.  I am using a user that is in the Administrator group on the DS account, and trying to update the profile for another user (that I created using the REST API w\ the same admin user).  It let me create the user in the site, but it is not letting me update the profile on that user.  I am getting a 404 error every time.

Comment: Through our separate emails, please verify that you are doing a PUT request and not a POST.

Comment: Using the PUT request instead of POST solved the 404 issue.  I did also have to use the SendOnBehalfOf feature in the X-DocuSign-Authentication header to enable updating other user profiles by an account administrator.